# AccordionSection Collapse all

Tags: lightning, javascript, salesforcedx, accordion

i'm facing an issue with a button to collapse All/Expand All of a lightning accordionSection
the problem is that i have a loop on the accordionSection, so the button only collapses/Expands the first section. i want it to expand all the accordionSections.

Component:

```html
<lightning:button label="Show All" onclick="{!c.ShowHideAll}" />
    <lightning:accordion aura:id="accordion"  allowMultipleSectionsOpen="true" activeSectionName="{!v.activeSections}">
        <!-- 1ere iteration pour afficher les sections-->
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.mapValues}"  var="mapKey" indexVar="key"> 
            <lightning:accordionSection name="A" label="{!mapKey.key}">
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.ratingEditMode == false}">
                    <!-- Display Form-->
                    <div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_readonly slds-form-element_edit slds-grow slds-hint-parent override--slds-form-element" style="border-bottom-width: 0px;">
                        <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="Opportunity">
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap full cols-2 forcePageBlockSectionRow">
```

Controller for the button :

```js
ShowHideAll: function (component, event) {
    let activeSections = component.get("v.activeSections");
    if (activeSections.length === 0) {
        component.set("v.activeSections",["A"]);
        event.getSource().set("v.label","Hide All");
    } else {
        component.set("v.activeSections",[]);
        event.getSource().set("v.label","Show All");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to keep another attribute to store the total possible set of active sections.  (maybe something like `allSections`) If you want to show all, just set the `activeSections` attribute to `allSections`.

You can use the `map` method to do this easily:

```
const sectionDetails = component.get('v.mapValues');
component.set('v.allSections', sectionDetails.map(sectionDetail => sectionDetail.key));
```

Within your component file, set the `lightning:accordionSection`'s `name` attribute to `{!v.mapKey.key}` and that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have hardcoded the name attribute of the `lightning:accordionSection` as **A**. This is causing issues to collapse/expand all the section at the same time.

As per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:accordion/documentation), To expand multiple sections programmatically, set allowMultipleSectionsOpen to true and pass in an array of section names instead.

```
handleClick: function (cmp, event) {
    var names = ['B','C']; //in your case you can get all the names of the accordion section
    // if you have JavaScript map you can use, Map.keys() to get all the keys from it
    cmp.set("v.activeSections", names);
}
```

coming to your case, You need to set the name attribute dynamically inside the loop. You can assign key to name attribute keeping in mind key is unique for all the item in the mapValues list.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.mapValues}"  var="mapKey" indexVar="key"> 
            <lightning:accordionSection name="{!mapKey.key}" label="{!mapKey.key}">
```